# How to save content from List<string> to a text file in C#?

Tags: c#, list, listbox, streamwriter

I have a listbox that displays the names of the files that are opened either with a dragDrop functionality or with an OpenFileDialog, the file paths are stored in the List named playlist, and the listbox only displays the names without paths and extensions. When my form closes, the playlist content is saved to a .txt file. When I open again my application, the content in the text file is stored again in the listbox and the playlist. But when I add new files after re-opening the form, I don't know why it leaves a blank line between the last files and the recently added ones.

This is the code I use to WRITE the content of playlist(List) in the txt file:

```
 private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "/Text.txt");
            foreach (String s in playlist)
            {
                str.WriteLine(s);
            }
            str.Close();
        }
```

This is the code used to READ the same txt file:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) //Form Load!!!
    {
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(Application.StartupPath + "/Text.txt");
        if(info.Exists)
        {
            if (info.Length > 0)
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "/Text.txt"); //StreamREADER
                try
                {
                    do
                    {
                        string currentRead = reader.ReadLine();
                        playlist.Add(currentRead);
                        listBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(currentRead));

                    } while (true);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                    listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "/Text.txt");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

    }
```

The code used to add files to listbox and playlist:

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Select File(s)";
        ofd.Filter = "Audio Files (*.mp3, *.wav, *.wma)|*.mp3|*.wav|*.wma";
        ofd.InitialDirectory = "C:/";
        ofd.RestoreDirectory = false;
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        ofd.ShowDialog();

        foreach (string s in ofd.FileNames)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s));
            playlist.Add(s);
        }


        listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

This is what I get when I add new files after re-opening my form:
[image: !!!!]

Thanks in advance, I hope StackOverflow community can help me!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: debug your code and you'll find the problem yourself :)

Issue is the use of the `WriteLine` method. The last line you write should use the `Write` method instead so that you don't have an empty line at the end. Alternatively and easier to implement is to only add non-empty lines to your playlist such like this:

```
// ...
do
{
    string currentRead = reader.ReadLine();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentRead)) // ignore empty lines
    {
        playlist.Add(currentRead);
       listBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(currentRead));
    }
} while (true);
```

As a side comment: `while (true)` and using exception handling is a bad approach to end a loop.

Comment: So, I should write the playlist's content with:  `str.Write(s)` I'm right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Ideally you avoid writing empty lines and so far there's just one which is the last line in your file. So if you loop through your playlist writing line by line make sure that you only add a new line if it's not the last playlist item. If you use `Write(s)` in general it will not work for multiple playlist items. Just try and debug and you'll see. In my opinion though you are better off doing a safe read which means do something similar to my example. You shouldn't trust a source in general even if your application has written it.

Comment: I used the safe read method and my form did not open. What could be wrong now?

Comment: Please DEBUG! The code example from above doesn't affect the dialogue handling.

Comment: My form does not open anymore on Debugging Mode too

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss: debugging helps to find problems and you will find the answer for why your form doesn't open. If not: write a **new** question ;-)  As for your problem stated above please try that once your application works again as it did when you asked your question.